# what is the need of creating multiple accounts with same email ID in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

I am new to Netsuite. 
While creating accounts on Netsuite, I found that i can create multiple accounts with same email ID (Netsuite does not check whether the email id is unique or not).

Is there any specific scenario where creating multiple accounts with same email ID will be useful in Netsuite ?

Answer (score 0):

You can associate one email address to multiple Netsuite account. When you login it will redirect you to a window where you can select the account where you want to use the existing login session.

Comment: Thanks for reply..but can you please elaborate more the situation where creating accounts with same email ID will result into advantage in administration of Netsuite(or advantage for a user).

Comment: @user2630332 As a developer I really find it useful. I have access to multiple client and NetSuite test development accounts with the same username and password, you dont have to remember multiple username and passwords

Answer (score 0):

No, It doesnt add or make any advantages to administration at all.  You SHOULD NOT associate two separate employees with the same Email ID.    Besides, when you set the same email to be associated across different places, it will force logout the current user when the next user attempts to login.

Advantage for the user for sure as they have access to all the roles associated to employee, customer, and partner records associated to their email address.  Definitely no advantage for NS administration.  If you are looking to do scalable things for implementation, then you need to do mass updates within netsuite across entities...don't try to use a single email placeholder as a shortcut for users or access as this gets derailed by the logout mechanism I mentioned above.  If you absolutely need multiple users to have access, you could do something like a limited partner or customer center role to an employee that can act as a parent for all assigned customers within their territory...but that basically is manipulating the system to work differently than intended and could be considered a violation of NS TOS...I would suggest to avoid this as it could mean they could shut off your account and access to your customization.